# Selecting list of object type after grouping in linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table such as the following:

ProductId, CategoryId
123, Category1
123, Category2
123, Category1

My parameter is productId and I need to return a list of type Category based on distinct categories for the given productId in the above table.

Comment: ProductId is supposedly unique? If so, there will always be 1 Product in your result set and storing it in a list seems silly.

Comment: Hmm the situation I am in is strange. I need to populate a dropdownlist of available product categories. I have a table with several fields but the key fields are ProductId and Category. In this table there are several rows such as (12345, Category1), (12345, Category1), (12345, Category2)... In this situation I need to return a distinct list of the categories based on productId.. So my list should be Category1, Category2.

Comment: So maybe I am going about this wrong.. The list that I should be returning and populating the dropdown with is Category, but I am relying on the table of multiple product rows to figure out the distinct categories for the selected product.

Comment: You don't have a Catagory table i presume? So you could `.Distinct()` the results of a category selection like `var pList = (from p in context.Products
 select p.Category).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: Correct, the categories are setup as a bunch of Global Constants in the system. So I am most likely going to populate my dropdown with objects of  type Type (which is a class in my system with fields like TypeId and TypeDescription). So I guess I should first return a list of Categories with the query you just gave and then create my TypeList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could leverage the .Distinct() function from LINQ to select all the distinct categories belonging to the specified productId.

```
var pList = (from p in context.Products 
where p.ProductId == productId 
select p.Category).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: So this would get me a list of Category names... and then I could use that list to create my Type object which will ultimately populate my dropdown correct?

Comment: Actually it would probably make sense to just return the list of string and populate the dropdown with that since both the value field and text field are CategoryName.

Comment: You might even be able to construct it into one query, i don't know how your TypeList looks like but i think it should be relatively trivial.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help... Err im not used to dealing with things like this since normally there would be a Category table and everything would be Id based.. Or at least a TypeListItem table with all of the Product Categories in it and everything would still be Id based and I would know which type I need to return and populate my dropdownlist with. In this case where the Categories are global constant strings it is weird, but I believe I can populate a DropDownList with a list of string so I am just going to do that rather than create a random object list.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = context.Products
  .Where(p=>p.ProductId==productId)
  .Distinct();
```